# Issues with brush Tool In illustrator using graphics tablet

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, brush

I'm using a Wacom graphics tablet and i'm trying to use the brush tool in Illustrator CS6 to write some 'curly' text for a project. It all looks fine when i'm drawing but as soon as i 'release' the pen from the tablet the paths seem to snap to something completely different to what I've drawn. See my screen shots below:

This is what it looks like as i'm drawing with the brush tool (before i release the pen):
[image]

And then as soon as i take my pen off the tablet the path automatically snaps and looks completely different to what i want:

[image]

I have tried playing around with all the settings ie. smoothness & fidelity etc but i cant seem to get the result i want?!?!
Is there a setting i need to adjust so when i take my pen off the tablet it doesn't change so drastically?

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that you need to adjust the fidelity and and smoothness. Fidelity controls how many points are added to the paths you are drawing and smoothness controls the amount Illustrator auto-smooths the shapes.

If you drag both sliders as low as they go then you will have minimal changes to your shapes. I normally keep them slightly above the minimum so I still get the smoothness without drastically changing the shape.

You can see the difference in fidilety/smoothness settings here:

[image]